# Capture the space key in a window containing several NSTextFields

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, keyboard-events, nstextfield

I have a large window with a number of `NSTextField` fields on it, and I would like to intercept the space bar even while any of the text fields have focus, so that pressing space at any time will cause a separate action.

Subclassing `NSTextField` and overriding `-keyUp:` allows me to detect the space key, but a blank is still inserted in the text field. `-keyDown:` does not fire at all.

For other keys like Return and the arrow keys, I could use the `control:textView:doCommandBySelector:` delegate method, but it does not fire with the space bar.

There's a lot of advice out there for `NSTextView`, but I have found none for `NSTextField`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you experimented with adding an *event monitor*? You create them via the `NSEvent` class method `addLocalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask(_:handler:)`
 and they give you first dibs on the events you specify. In your case you'd add a monitor for `keyDown` events, then in the associated block you decide what to do with them. At the end of the block you can return the event just as it arrived, in which case it will behave normally, you can swallow the event (return `nil`), or you can modify the event by creating a new event object and returning that instead. Here's an example:

```
// You can add monitors anywhere - I've chosen the AppDelegate for
// this simple example.
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    [NSEvent addLocalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:NSKeyDownMask
                                          handler:^NSEvent * (NSEvent * theEvent) {

          if (theEvent.keyCode == 49) {
              NSLog(@"swallowing spacebar");
              theEvent = nil;

          }

          return theEvent;
    }];
}
```

Comment: After some playing with that (I have to add/remove the event monitor when the window becomes/loses key to avoid interference with other windows) this seems to be the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Since the behavior you're trying to implement is at the level of the window (or perhaps a view that's an ancestor of all of the text fields), you should consider implementing [`-performKeyEquivalent:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSResponder_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSResponder/performKeyEquivalent:) at that level instead of trying to capture the space key in each individual text field.

In your implementation, check the event's `modifierFlags` to make sure none of Control, Option, or Command are pressed (assuming you only want to handle unmodified space key presses) and if its `charactersIgnoringModifiers` equals `@" "`. If so, do what you want and then return `YES` to indicate you've handled the key event. Otherwise, return `NO` to allow it to be handled normally.

Comment: Not sure if I undertood that right. If I implement `-performKeyEquivalent:` in an `NSTextField` subclass which I assign to the text fields in question, it is never called. If I do it in the window's content view, no luck either. Can you elaborate?

Comment: To be more precise: in the content view that contains the text fields, `-performKeyEquivalent:` is only called when no field has focus. But I need to intercept the space bar even when a field is currently being edited.

Answer (score 0):

If you know how to do it for `NSTextView`, then you know how to do it for `NSTextField`, because `NSTextField` uses an `NSTextView` called the "field editor" for editing.  You can get the window's default field editor like so:

```
NSTextView* fieldEd = [myWindow fieldEditor: YES forObject: nil];
```

You can also use a window delegate to provide a custom field editor.

Comment: Hmm, sound promising, but somehow doesn't work for me; `NSText *fieldEditor = [self.view.window fieldEditor:YES forObject:nil];` (called from the view controller's `viewDidLoad`) returns `nil`. Any idea why?

Comment: I'm not real familiar with use of view controllers.  Is it possible that at the time of `viewDidLoad`, the view has not yet been placed into a window?  In which case `self.view.window` would be nil.

Comment: You guessed right. I've solved that by setting the delegate for the fieldEditor later (in `-viewWillAppear`), but the only promising delegate method (`-textDidChange:`) is never executed either. I feel like I'm overlooking some simple solution... Supplying my own fieldEditor subclass appears to be very complicated (you need to override every single method and must not call `super` - no clue why).

Answer (score -1):

So you might want to look into ReactiveCocoa

Go to the video on this [page](https://realm.io/news/swift-summit-colin-eberhardt-reactivecocoa/) and look at **5:14** to see something similar to what you might like.

ReactiveCocoa can be hooked into all your text fields and then any time a space is hit a signal handler could pick it up.  (Probably, however, more than you want to get into).

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't help a bit. My project is in Objective-C, and you correctly guessed that I don't want to change the whole architecture of my project in order to implement one simple UI feature.